# OrderBy().ThenBy().ThenBy() not giving expected result on a List of entities

Tags: c#, linq

Having trouble understanding why my simple ordering doesn't work as expected. Here's the offending line:

```
return messages.OrderBy(o => o.MessageType)
               .ThenBy(p => p.IsUrgent)
               .ThenByDescending(p => p.Timestamp)
               .ToList();
```

The last two orderings (Urgent and Timestamp) don't work correctly. My results are either ordered by IsUrgent or Timestamp, but never both.

My end result should be all messages are sorted by type (there's only 3 types New, Saved, Deleted). Then in each type, have urgent messages first, and then order by the timestamp.

**UPDATE**

You asked for more info, so here it is

```
[TestMethod]
    public void Messages_should_sort_correctly()
    {
        var contact = new Models.Contact(); //just to satisfy the object

        var expectedOrder = new string[] { "5", "6", "12", "3", "10", "9", "4", "8", "11", "13", "2", "7", "1" };
        var messages = new List<IMessage>
        {
            new Models.Message { FileName = "1",   MessageType = MessageType.Deleted,   Timestamp = 31,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "2",   MessageType = MessageType.Deleted,   Timestamp = 34,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "3",   MessageType = MessageType.Inbox,     Timestamp = 11,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "4",   MessageType = MessageType.Saved,     Timestamp = 25,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "5",   MessageType = MessageType.Inbox,     Timestamp = 14,  Contact = contact, IsUrgent = true },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "6",   MessageType = MessageType.Inbox,     Timestamp = 13,  Contact = contact, IsUrgent = true },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "7",   MessageType = MessageType.Deleted,   Timestamp = 32,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "8",   MessageType = MessageType.Saved,     Timestamp = 22,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "9",   MessageType = MessageType.Saved,     Timestamp = 23,  Contact = contact, IsUrgent = true },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "10",  MessageType = MessageType.Saved,     Timestamp = 24,  Contact = contact, IsUrgent = true },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "11",  MessageType = MessageType.Saved,     Timestamp = 21,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "12",  MessageType = MessageType.Inbox,     Timestamp = 12,  Contact = contact },
            new Models.Message { FileName = "13",  MessageType = MessageType.Deleted,   Timestamp = 33,  Contact = contact, IsUrgent = true }
        };

        messageServiceMock.Setup(m => m.GetAllMessagesAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(messages as IList<IMessage>)).AtMostOnce();

        var result = service.Messages; //this property returns the messages from our mock, and then sorts and orders
        var actualOrder = result.Select(m => m.FileName);


        //expected order "5", "6", "12", "3", "10", "9", "4", "8", "11", "13", "2", "7", "1"
        //actual order   "12", "3", "5", "6", "4", "8", "11", "10", "9", "2", "7", "1", "13" 
        Assert.IsTrue(actualOrder.SequenceEqual(expectedOrder));
    }
```

And here is where all the magic/confusion happens

```
private List<Domain.Interfaces.IMessage> messages = new List<Domain.Interfaces.IMessage>();
    public IList<Domain.Interfaces.IMessage> Messages
    {
        get
        {
            if (!messages.Any())
            {
                messages = messageService.GetAllMessagesAsync().Result.ToDomain().ToList();
            }

            return messages.OrderBy(o => o.MessageType).ThenBy(p => p.IsUrgent == true).ThenByDescending(p => p.Timestamp).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what type is `IsUrgent`?

Comment: Hard to comment/suggest, provide an example (mock data) that produces failure case?

Comment: Is it executed against the database? Or against any other external source? Is there any custom linq provider involved? Is it just a plain linq to objects?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @HariPrasad - Yah, my apologies. I've updated with the unit test I'm trying to pass.

Comment: @Matt You forgot to attach test results dump, can we have it please?

Comment: @KonstantinChernov - Having trouble with generating the actual trx file, so I've put in comments for the actual and expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: When I use `ThenBy(p => !p.IsUrgent)`, I get the correct (=expected) result in LinqPad.

Comment: @HansKesting - Wow...just...wow. So ordering by a Boolean == true puts them at the end. I has assumed it was the other way around. If you put an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @HansKesting Thanks for clarifications - added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the source of confusion is clear now. When u sort upon Boolean u get `false` values coming first and `true` values coming second. So the recipe for the TS is either to use

```
return messages.OrderBy(o => o.MessageType)
               .ThenByDescending(p => p.IsUrgent)
               .ThenByDescending(p => p.Timestamp)
               .ToList();
```

or

```
return messages.OrderBy(o => o.MessageType)
               .Then(p => !p.IsUrgent)
               .ThenByDescending(p => p.Timestamp)
               .ToList();
```

Imo the first way is clearer and more intuitive, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically it should work as expected. You can trace your query using:

```
IQueryable<Message> query = messages
                           .OrderBy(o => o.MessageType)
                           .ThenBy(p => p.IsUrgent)
                           .ThenByDescending(p => p.Timestamp);
//debug query.ToString() to see the generated sql
//should be SELECT XXX WHERE YYY ORDER BY MessageType, IsUrgent, Timestamp DESC
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: this should be a omment.

Comment: @DanielA.White I disagree. OP asks why it's not working as expected, I told him it should work, somewhere else is wrong, and I told him the solution to debug it. Isn't it an answer?

Comment: @DanielA.White: Seems like an appropriate way to respond to a "question" with no question.

Comment: @DanielA.White Seems too harsh to downvote guys trying to help and clarify things out. Looks like you are applying rules too formally. I also upvote this.

Comment: @DannyChen - Thanks, I'll check this out and see what comes out of it. I've also updated my question with the unit test I'm working on.

Answer (score 2):

Quick debug shows this is not the case of linq2objects.

Test code:

```
void Main()
{
    var messages = GenerateTestData();  
    var results = messages.OrderBy(o => o.Type)
               .ThenBy(p => p.IsUrgent)
               .ThenByDescending(p => p.TimeStamp)
               .ToList();          
    foreach (var m in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.ToString());
    }
}

public List<Message> GenerateTestData()
{
    var result = new List<Message>(10){

    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.New, IsUrgent = true, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Saved, IsUrgent = true, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(9).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Deleted, IsUrgent = false, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(8).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Deleted, IsUrgent = false, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(7).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Saved, IsUrgent = false, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(6).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.New, IsUrgent = true, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(5).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Saved, IsUrgent = true, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(4).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Saved, IsUrgent = false, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(3).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.Deleted, IsUrgent = true, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(2).Ticks},
    new Message(){ Type = MessageType.New, IsUrgent = false, TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(1).Ticks}
    };
    return result;
}

public enum MessageType
{
    New,
    Saved,
    Deleted
}
public class Message
{
    public MessageType Type{get;set;}
    public bool IsUrgent{get;set;}
    public long TimeStamp {get;set;}

    public  override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Type: {0}, IsUrgent: {1}, TimeStamp: {2}",this.Type, this.IsUrgent, this.TimeStamp);
    }
}
```

leads to the following perfectly correct and expected results

```
Type: New, IsUrgent: False, TimeStamp: 635922806855227531
Type: New, IsUrgent: True, TimeStamp: 635922806855317531
Type: New, IsUrgent: True, TimeStamp: 635922806855267531
Type: Saved, IsUrgent: False, TimeStamp: 635922806855277531
Type: Saved, IsUrgent: False, TimeStamp: 635922806855247531
Type: Saved, IsUrgent: True, TimeStamp: 635922806855307531
Type: Saved, IsUrgent: True, TimeStamp: 635922806855257531
Type: Deleted, IsUrgent: False, TimeStamp: 635922806855297531
Type: Deleted, IsUrgent: False, TimeStamp: 635922806855287531
Type: Deleted, IsUrgent: True, TimeStamp: 635922806855237531
```

I was assuming `IsUrgent` is `bool` and  `TimeStamp` is `long`.
So, we definitely need more details from TS.

Comment: This isn't an answer

Comment: @DanielA.White yeah but too big for a comment

Comment: @KonstantinChernov - You assumed correct for the data types. I've added my current unit test with data.